# Transpose/Add new colums in SAS

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have this data in SAS:

```
+-----------+-------+
| PartnerNo | SAPNo |
+-----------+-------+
| P1        |   123 |
| P1        |   124 |
| P1        |   125 |
| P2        |   126 |
| P2        |   127 |
| P3        |   128 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Now I want a row per partner and a new column for each SAPNo.
Like this:

```
+-----------+------+------+------+
| PartnerNo | SAP1 | SAP2 | SAP3 |
+-----------+------+------+------+
| P1        |  123 |  124 |  125 |
| P2        |  126 |  127 |      |
| P3        |  128 |      |      |
+-----------+------+------+------+
```

This needs to be dynamic. There could be up to 8 SAPNo per PartnerNo.

I m using SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: look up proc transpose, bud

Comment: I tried to count the SAPNumbers and go from there through a series of queries, but that wasnt very elegant.  `data partner_new;
set partner;
by NO;
if first.NO then New_column=0;
New_column+1;
run;`

Answer (score 0):

Proc transpose is powerfull, but not that intuitive.
This is the sollution:

```
proc transpose prefix=SAP
    data=iHave
    out=iNeed (drop=_name_);

    by PartnerNo;
    var SAPNo;
run;
```

Of course `data` specifies the input and `out` the output.

`var SAPNo` specifies that you want the values of that variable to be listed in columns.

SAS procedures often generate documentary variables, enclosed in undersores. Proc transposem for instandce, creates a `_name_` field. If you specify multiple variable sin the `var` statement, the procedure will generate multiple lines per `id` variable. This `_name_` then indicates where the values come from. We do not need it, so we drop it. Alternatively, we could have remove all variable starting with an underscore with `drop=_:`. This comes in handy for procedures generating multiple documentary variable if you need none of them.

By defauld, these colomns are named `col1`, `col2` etc. I changed this with the `prefix` option. Often this is not what you want, because the destination column is named in another variable. Then [use the `id` statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000063668.htm).

`by PartnerNo` specifies you want a new observation *(or row, if you prefer database vocabulary over SAS vocabulary)*  for eacht value that variable

Comment: That works great thanks! I played arround with transpose but I was missing the "var" part.